# Service not being injected within Hangfire job in Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, hangfire

Disclaimer: I'm very new to the C#, ASP.NET Core and Dependency Injection world. I've created a simple Blazor Server App from the default template, which scaffolds a mock weather service and shows data fetched from it in a table. Now I want the table to be automatically updated every five seconds, for which I am using the `Hangfire.AspNetCore` and `Hangfire.MemoryStorage` packages. So I've slightly modified the `FetchData.razor` component to look like this:

```
@page "/fetchdata"

@using WeatherTest.Data
@using Hangfire

@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    public async Task UpdateForecasts()
    {
      forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
      BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => UpdateForecasts(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      await UpdateForecasts();
    }
}
```

This is the weather service:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeatherTest.Data
{
    public class WeatherForecastService
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync(DateTime startDate)
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

And the services configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    services.AddHangfire(c => c.UseMemoryStorage());
    services.AddHangfireServer();
}
```

The problem is that `UpdateForecasts()` succeeds when called from `OnInitializedAsync()`, but fails when called by Hangfire throwing the following exception at `forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);`:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
>
> WeatherTest.Pages.FetchData.ForecastService.get returned null.

It seems to me that, since the Hangfire worker runs in another thread, then the `WeatherForecastService` doesn't get injected. Am I right? Is it possible for a singleton to be used from multiple threads, or each thread should have its own service instance? At last, how should I solve this?

Comment: I think you're missing a piece of the information. When scheduling a background job, in this case, the user is acting on the main thread and your job is executed in another thread. You are doing a fire-and-forget type job, you're scheduling it and saying goodbye. One way I'm thinking might work, is by creating an event and subscribing to it inside the page itself, then raise that event from the WeatherService whenever it's updated.

Comment: You could use a simple timer service in this instance, but I'm guessing there are other reasons to try and use hangfire?  For this to work you need hangfire to get the service reference and interface directly with the service, and then use events as suggested above.  Not having any experience with Hangfire I'll leave others to tell you if/how to do it.

Comment: @Dennisv.W. Thanks Dennis. I think I'm aware of that, and was planning tocheck inside the job routine whether the connection is still alive; if not, just cancel the jo b and stop scheduling it. Concerning your proposal, wouldn't that make the service update itself even when there are no connected clients? I would like to call for an update only when there is a user viewing the `FetchData.razor` component. Also, the data returned by the service should be different for each user, although that's not the case in this example.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks. Actually I am just seeking for the simplest way to do this, so I would have no problem in dropping Hangfire if it is not required at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `FetchData` component that uses a standard `Timer`.

A few points:

1. I've added a `Task.Delay` in to emulate a slow connection and to show that the page is refreshing.
2. `StateHasChanged` is wrapped like this `await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` to ensure it gets run on the UI context thread.
3. Implements `IDisposable` as we have the Timer event handler to disconnect.

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

@using StackOverflow.Server.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

<div class="p-2">
    <button class="btn @this.btnCss" @onclick="ToggleTimer">@this.btnText</button>
</div>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);

    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    private string btnCss => aTimer.Enabled ? "btn-danger" : "btn-success";

        private string btnText => aTimer.Enabled ? "Stop" : "Start";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        aTimer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }

    public async void TimerElapsed(Object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        forecasts = null;
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        await Task.Delay(500);
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void ToggleTimer()
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = !aTimer.Enabled;
        this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
       => aTimer!.Elapsed -= TimerElapsed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well, so I think the usage of Hangfire was overkill for this simple task. I'll accept this in the following days if I get no other answer that addresses the original issue, just to be consistent! :)