# Why Is My Blazor Server App's Timer Is Not Refreshing Its Components

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am completely re-writing this question as nothing has made sense to anybody - I apologize for the issues.

To start, I have a Singleton service, called LocalSystemService, that handles RESTful communications between the Blazor Server App and a separate Web API system running on a separate server.  I have added that service into my Blazor application using the following call:

```
services.AddScoped<ILocalSystemService, LocalSystemService>();
```

I have now moved away from a simple Timer and to a separate Service in response to other articles I have read.  This service is called CheckLDC and is registered using the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<CheckLDC>();
```

That service is constructed as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Telerik.Blazor;
using Telerik.Blazor.Components;
using Frontend.Data;
using Frontend.Services;

namespace Frontend.Services
{
    public class LDCExecutedEventArgs : EventArgs { }
    

    public class CheckLDC : IDisposable
    {
        public event EventHandler<LDCExecutedEventArgs> JobExecuted;
        void OnJobExecuted()
        {
            JobExecuted?.Invoke(this, new LDCExecutedEventArgs());
        }

        #region Globals
        static ReaderWriterLock locker = new ReaderWriterLock();
        private System.Timers.Timer checkRemoteData;
        private bool _Running;
        [Inject]
        public ILocalSystemService LocalSystemService { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public ILogger<CheckLDC> _logger { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public IMemoryCache _cache { get; set; }
        private const string LocationCacheName = "LocalSystem";
        #endregion

        public void StartExecuting()
        {
            if (!_Running)
            {
                // Initiate a Timer
                checkRemoteData = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
                checkRemoteData.Elapsed += HandleTimer;
                checkRemoteData.AutoReset = true;
                checkRemoteData.Enabled = true;

                _Running = true;
            }
        }

        private async void HandleTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            **This call results in a NULL for the LocalSystemService!!!**
            **if (LocalSystemService.IsThereAnUpdate().Result)**
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        locker.AcquireWriterLock(int.MaxValue);

                        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(LocationCacheName, out transferSystem))
                        {
                            //We need to grab everything:
                            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                            #region Location
                            try
                            {
                                _cache.Set(LocationCacheName, LocalSystemService.GetLocalSystem().Result);
                            }
                            catch (Exception locWriteX)
                            {
                                _logger.LogError("Failed to restore location locally with the error: " + locWriteX.ToString());
                            }
                            #endregion
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        locker.ReleaseWriterLock();
                    }
                });
            }

            // Notify any subscribers to the event
            OnJobExecuted();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_Running)
            {
                checkRemoteData?.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then placed this code in my main component behind

```
    [Inject]
    public ILocalSystemService LocalSystemService { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public CheckLDC CheckTheBackend {get; set;}
```

Note that I am using a Memory Cache to store data across requests.  Wit the injection in place, my OnInit method looks as follows:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //This call uses the LocalSystemService to grab and store the main data class into the cache 
            CurrentSystem = CreateCaches().Result;
        });
        //These are my event subscriptions
        CheckTheBackend.JobExecuted += HandleJobExecuted;
        CheckTheBackend.StartExecuting();
    }
```

Finally, the method being called on JobExecute is:

```
public async void HandleJobExecuted(object sender, LDCExecutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
```

Now I am getting a NULL exception when trying to call the LocalSystemService from the CheckLDC's HandleTimer event call - I bold typed the call that continues to fail.  I have tried AddTransient and AddScope for the LocalSystemService but nothing works.  In the Blazor app, I can call LocalSystemService without any issues - but is ALWAYS fails in the CheckLDC singleton.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to provide some code. Make a mock-up with the Timer and StateHasChanged. Replace the API with a Task.Delay or something. See [mre]

Comment: Without any code to work with, see this question that I answered recently on refreshing the WeatherForecast List in FetchData - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69967013/service-not-being-injected-within-hangfire-job-in-blazor-server-app/69978739#69978739

Comment: Sorry for not including the code!  I have stepped through and watched as each of the StateHasChanged methods are called exactly when I want them to be called.  It does not change the UI no matter how long I wait.

Comment: I added in an interface for the CheckLDC service, changed the service call for both services to 
    'services.AddScoped<ILocalSystemService, LocalSystemService>();'
    'services.AddScoped<ICheckLDC, CheckLDC>();'

And I am still getting the error that the LocalSystemService is null during this call:

    'private async void HandleTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)'
        '{'
            'if (LocalSystemService.IsThereAnUpdate().Result)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but it is hard to follow the flow of execution without having a complete reproducible code sample. However, the following code snippet, based on the FetchData page, and your code (I tried to be as true as possible to your code) works. The commented code is superfluous. Copy and test...then try to apply it to your program, and report of issues.

```
@page "/fetchdata"

@using WebApplication1.Data
@using System.Timers;

@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@implements IDisposable

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;
    private static System.Timers.Timer checkRemoteData;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);

        //await Task.Run(() =>
        //{
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now); //.Result;
 // What is ShowModal? Are you setting it to true somewhere ?
 // Perhaps this is why you do not see the changes, if you design 
 // to show the changes in a window modal                                                                             

 //  ShowModal = false;
                                                                          //});

        //This works and calls the main method every second
        checkRemoteData = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
        checkRemoteData.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        checkRemoteData.AutoReset = true;
        checkRemoteData.Enabled = true;
    }

    private async void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (LocalSystemService.IsThereAnUpdate().Result)
        //{
              
              // await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
              // I have used the same call as in the OnInit - niether one works!
             forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
             await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()); //.ConfigureAwait(false);
              // What is this for ? Are you trying to emulate 
              // delay? Just increase the interval (to 4000...)
             // await Task.Delay(500);
             // Not needed
             // await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        //}

        
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        checkRemoteData.Elapsed -= OnTimedEvent;
    }
}
```

### Update:

I've added the following method to the WeatherForecastService  in order to emulate `LocalSystemService.IsThereAnUpdate().Result`

```
 public Task<bool> IsThereAnUpdate()
 {
      return Task.FromResult( true);
 }
```

And added also this:

```
if (ForecastService.IsThereAnUpdate().Result)
{

 }
```

And now when the IsThereAnUpdate returns true, the UI is updated, and when it returns false, it does not.

Comment: Sorry about the extraneous code - the ShowModal handles a modal window and can be ignored.  The ForecastServer in your case in akin to my LocalSystemService,  The rest of the code you see in the OnTimedEvent is me simply adding more and more attempts to get the UI to refresh.  I will edit the question to clear things up as your solution SHOULD work but it does not.

Comment: @Ken, my code sample as is does work. That is certain. See the Update section in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use property injection here - that is for components only.

You will need to use constructor injection for CheckLDC

```cs
private readonly ILocalSystemService LocalSystemService;
private readonly ILogger<CheckLDC> _logger;
private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

public CheckLDC(ILocalSystemService localSystemService,
  ILogger<CheckLDC> logger,
  IMemoryCache cache)
{
  LocalSystemService = localSystemService;
  _logger = logger;
  _cache = cache;
}
```